# Having transparent background behind React-bootstrap Modal window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am using React Bootstrap and Modal.
I want the Modal to open, and behind it is the window that I was in (i.e. to have the background behind the Modal to be transparent).

When I am currently getting is, when I click on the link the Modal opens in a new page with empty background.

ie.

<<<<<<<<< Current screenshot >>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[image: current_screenshot]

What I want to achieve is something similar to the following, were the background behind the Modal is transparent:
ie.

<<<<<<<<< Desired screenshot >>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<Modal.Dialog>
    <Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Title>New Component</Modal.Title>
        <Button variant="light">X</Button>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
        <h5 className="mb-4">Component information</h5>
        <Form >
            <FormGroup>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={6} className="mb-3">
                            <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control required type="text" placeholder="Component Name" />
                    </Col>

                    <Col md={6} className="mb-3">
                            <Form.Label>Quantity</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control required type="number" placeholder="Quantity" />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </FormGroup>
        </Form>
    </Modal.Body>
</Modal.Dialog>
```

Here is the routing part, where I am linking the page to a route:
Routing:

```
<Switch>
  <Router>
    <Route exact path="/app/new" component={NewComponentForm}/>
  </Router>
</Switch>
```

Comment: How is it opening in new page ? can you share some more code what triggers the modal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Col,
  Container,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Modal,
  Row,
} from "react-bootstrap";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row className="justify-content-md-center align-items-center">
        <Button
          className="d-flex justify-content-center"
          variant="primary"
          onClick={handleShow}
        >
          Launch demo modal
        </Button>
        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Title>New Component</Modal.Title>
            <Button variant="light" onClick={handleClose}>
              X
            </Button>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <h5 className="mb-4">Component information</h5>
            <Form>
              <FormGroup>
                <Row>
                  <Col md={6} className="mb-3">
                    <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                      required
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Component Name"
                    />
                  </Col>

                  <Col md={6} className="mb-3">
                    <Form.Label>Quantity</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                      required
                      type="number"
                      placeholder="Quantity"
                    />
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </FormGroup>
            </Form>
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

There is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-modal-n059s?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching, the Modal element in React-Bootstrap @8.19.2 renders as

```html
<div class="modal-dialog"> <--- React <Modal>
    <div class="modal-content"> <---- ????
        <div class="modal-header"> <---- Modal.Header
          
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"> <---- Modal.Body

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The modal-content `div` is responsible for the background, although the header has an extra one behind the text

So I made a CSS file with the following content:

```css
div.transparent div.modal-content {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
}
div.transparent div.modal-content div.modal-header {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
    padding-bottom: 0% !important;
    padding-top: 0% !important;
}
```

Included it in the `main.tsx` via `import` and added it to my modal's classes.